# Assign shortcut key to a macro in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: shortcut-keys

In LibreOffice Writer version 7.3.7.2/LibreOffice Community for Ubuntu 22.04.4 assigning a shortcut key to a macro has changed. The prior instructions were Tools>Customize>Category expand LibreOffice Macros. Now, LibreOffice Macros is not in the Category list. Where is it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found it! There is a category "LibreOffice Macros" further down in the Category window. Problem is, for weak eyed geezers who use Display Resolution 1280x720, the window does not show all the categories. Changing the Display Resolution temporarily to reduce the magnification reveals all of the window and opens up all the choices!!

Comment: Isn't there a scrollbar for the Category list? That should allow you to continue using 1280x720 (which btw, blurs the text. You can replace it with the highest resolution, then set "display scale" to what you want, so that the text looks clearer)

Comment: @Daniel T - I looked high and low for a scroll bar and did not see it. But seeing things is part of my problem...